# Would insertion of a dielectric slab change the electric field pattern due to a system of different point charges well separated from each other.?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

We have a system of point charges in free space ,due to which  electric field has some value  at each point . Now we introduce a dielectric material into this configuration at some location where no point charge is present . Would the presence of this dielectric change the value of electric field at any point outside it ? Inside the dielectric electric field would surely get changed from free space values due to charges appearing due to polarization?
What I have understood is that if two point charges are kept in an infinite dielectric medium  at some fixed separation the net force on each charge gets changed but the values of action reaction pair does not change.
Now two question arises :

*If a small dielectric slab is introduced between two equal and opposite fixed point charges would the magnitude of net force on each charge change ? Would net force on each increase or decrease? If yes it means dielectric has changed the net field at the location  of charges.

- what if the above situation is reconsidered by assuming both fixed point charges are positive? In this case would negative induced charges appear on both the faces of dielectric?

Comment: A dielectric material contains charges, so of course it changes the "field pattern".

Answer (score 1):

"If a small dielectric slab is introduced between two equal and opposite fixed point charges would the magnitude of net force on each charge change ?"

It would increase.

The dielectric would be polarised by the field due to the point charges. Because this field is non-uniform, there would be regions of net charge both inside the slab and on its surfaces. As a result the half-thickness of the slab closest to the positive point charge will have a net negative charge and the half-thickness closest to the negative charge will have a net positive charge.

The force on the positive point charge will be the sum of the force (attractive) due to the negative point charge and the force due to the dielectric. The latter will also be attractive because the part of the dielectric with a negative charge is closer to the positive point charge than the part of the dielectric with a positive charge.

The fall-off with distance of field strength due to the dielectric's charges occurs because the charges are not spread uniformly over the area of the dielectric, but are concentrated in regions near the point charges. [It is for the same reason that a quantitative treatment of your question would be difficult.]